# Rails - POST request: Error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, routes, internal-server-error

I'm a beginner coder and I'm trying to create an application using React as my front end and Ruby on Rails for my back end. Anytime I press the sign up button and send the request to server I'm receiving an error and I cannot figure out what it is. Help!

**Console:**

SignUp.js:17

```
POST http://localhost:4000/users 500 (Internal Server Error)
SignUp.js:26 
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:4000/users', redirected: false, status: 500, ok: false, …} body: (...) body Used: true headers: Headers {} ok: false redirected: false status: 500 statusText: "Internal Server Error" type: "basic" url: "http://localhost:4000/users" [[Prototype]]: Response
```

When trying to access localhost

```
GET http://localhost:3000/me 500 (Internal Server Error)
favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**Rails Server:**

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)):
  
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:2:in `<class:UsersController>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<main>'
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-11-02 23:09:07 -0400
  
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)):
  
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:2:in `<class:UsersController>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

**React front end**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from "react";

function SignUp() {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    
    function handleSignUp(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        const user = {
            username,
            password
        }

        fetch("/users",{
            method: "POST",
            header: {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(user)
        }).then(r => {

        r.json()
        console.log(r)})
    
    }



    return (
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSignUp}>
            <p>Username</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
            <p>Password</p>
         <input
          type="text"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SignUp;
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  # Routing logic: fallback requests for React Router.
  # Leave this here to help deploy your app later!

  

  post "/login", to: "sessions#create"
  delete "logout", to: "sessions#destroy"

  get "/me", to: "users#show"
  post "/users", to: "users#create"
 

  get "*path", to: "fallback#index", constraints: ->(req) { !req.xhr? && req.format.html? }


end
```

**Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    wrap_parameters
rescue_from ActiveRecord:RecordInvalid, with: :record_invalid_response

    def create
        user = User.create!(user_params)
        render json: user, status: :created
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
    end

    def show
        user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        if user
            render json: user
        else
            render json: { error: "Not authorized" }, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.permit(:username, :password)
        # :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :email
    end

    def record_invalid_response(user)
        render json: {error: user.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

end
```

Comment: I am not a React person so I may be wrong, but it seems `wrap_parameters` is expecting params that it cannot find. Before your fetch, maybe you can `console.log(user)` to inspect the values.

Answer (score 0):

:The error comes from the fact that `wrap_parameters` expects some arguments, see https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html.

Now, for a JSON request, you don't need to call this function as Rails does it by default. But then I suppose Rails wraps your params with a `user` key and so you need to change your params processing, something like this should work:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :record_invalid_response

  def create
    user = User.create!(user_params)
    render json: user, status: :created
  end

  def show
    user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    if user
      render json: user
    else
      render json: { error: "Not authorized" }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
    # :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :email
  end

  def record_invalid_response(user)
    render json: {error: user.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Note: I also removed the `rescue` from the create action as it would prevent your controller-level `rescue_from` from being used